# Extract multiple text from string onto columns in hive with regexp_extract

Tags: string, hive

how can I extract or separate the string value into columns?

{"orderSupplier":{"name":"ABC"},"orderRegion":{"name":"AUS,USA,GBR"}}

into:
orderSupplier       orderRegion1       orderRegion2        orderRegion3
ABC                 AUS                 USA                  GBR